# Beamer metropolis theme: change color of section page

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I would like to know a way to change the background color of the section page in the beamer metropolis theme.

I tried something like this:

```
\setbeamercolor{sectionpage}{fg=blue,bg=blue}
```

but it didn't work. Any ideas?

cheers,

Comment: Please do not regard this as a criticism but your chances of getting an answer will, according to my experience, increase quite a bit if you promote your code fragment to a small document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` since then others won't have to do that for you.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

It is possible to do much damage to the aesthetic styles by changing colours on each frame so you need to avoid glaring contrasts like whot I have done.

I will simply point you a snippet producing the above frames generated by adding after the **default title page**

```
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=cyan!50!white}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=yellow!50!white}
\setbeamercolor{section title}{fg=white,bg=red!50!black}
\section{Introduction}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to make the section pages look like `standout` frame style in metropolis theme. You can do this by including the following in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginSection{
  {
    \metroset{background=dark}
    \frame[plain,c,noframenumbering]{\sectionpage}
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice suggestion. I don't know why but the "\metroset{background=dark}" did nothing when I tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer by tachyon, I added the following to my preamble

```
\AtBeginSection{
  {
    \setbeamercolor{section title}{fg=white} % font color 
    \frame[standout]{\sectionpage} % the "standout" keyword makes the background dark
  }
}
```